# PreAuthorize, PostAuthorize, PreFilter, PostFilter with SpringBoot REST crashes

Tags: spring, spring-security

My repository looks like this:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "users", path = "users")
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
    @Override
    @PreAuthorize("permitAll")
    @PostFilter("filterObject.email == principal.name")
    public Iterable<User> findAll();
}
```

But no matter what I write as the condition of those pre/post annotations, my applications srashes on start (using `gradle bootRun`) with this following terribly long stack trace: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=sxJCivPQ

Any idea what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a circular dependency, the repository was used in authentication class! I had to create another repository, almost the same as the `@RepositoryRestResource`, but remove all the `@SomethingRestSomething` annotations and all `@PrePost` annotations. And us this new stripped down repository in authentication classes.